# Posting variable from js to php, strange encode64 situation in php?

Tags: php, string

I have 2 files screen.js and test.php.
I have this simple php code in test.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['img'])) {
$img = $_POST['img'];
$comma = strpos($img, ',');
$data = substr($img, $comma+1);
file_put_contents('MyFile.jpg', base64_decode($data));
}
?>
```

I have 2 situations:

1. When I send via ajax img variable which contains jpg file, as string base64 from screen.js to test.php the script save a file on server side but I can't open it. I got error while opening!! :(
2. While i debug the screen.js I know what img variable contains. When I copy and paste the contents of the img variable and save into test.php as below everyting is ok.

   if (isset($_POST['img'])) {
   $data2 = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMC...etc.';
   file_put_contents('MyFile.jpg', base64_decode($data2));
   }

So what's wrong?

Comment: Probably, the complete encoded string is not being transferred, did you check the length of the strings that AJAX sends and you copy pasted? Are they the same?

Comment: Yes I check it its the same length and no difference I notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 encoded data may contain + symbols. If you are sending the data as a normal URL encoded parameter then php will decode the `+` into a space which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: So after decode I should string replace + to space and everything should be ok?

Comment: Before you base64 decode you'd need to replace spaces with `+`.

Comment: Yes I know now everything is ok:)